# Open Module_name gives a compiler-error

Tags: module, compiler-errors, ocaml

I cannot compile an extremely simple ocaml program test2.ml

```
open Test1

print_string " Hello "
```

with test1.ml containing only 1 line

```
type program = string
```

And test1.ml is compiled:

```
bash-3.2$ ocamlc test1.ml
bash-3.2$ ls test1.*
test1.cmi   test1.cmo   test1.ml
```

Anyone know why test1.ml does not compile?? Thank you.

More info. It's quite strange because, test2.ml compiles if I comment out its first line "open ..." OR
if I comment out its 3rd line "print_string..." but they cannot coexist!

Answer (score 5):

Printing the error you received *would* have been helpful. For the reference, it's:

```
File "test2.ml", line 3, characters 0-12:
Error: Syntax error
```

The reason for this is a bit complex. The normal syntax is for a file to be a sequence of top-level statements, such as type definitions, `let` (without `in`), module definition/opening/including and so on.

Expressions such as `print_string "Hello"` are never treated as top-level statements unless the meaning is completely unambiguous, which 99% of the time involves separating them from the previous and following statement with a `;;`

So, you could write the following:

```
open Test1 ;;
print_string " Hello "
```

And it would work. Most of the time, though, it is preferable to keep the file clean by turning the expression into a top-level `let`:

```
open Test1
let () = print_string " Hello "
```

This also has the benefit of making sure that the function returns `unit`, which is always nice to have.

Comment: You are right. However, it seems quite confusing all these.  In my humble opinion, this strange imperative part should have been more worked on by those Ocaml designers.